# Dataset Labeled as not found or Corrupt, but the dataset is not corrupt

Tags: pytorch, dataset, google-colaboratory

I have been trying to use this Github (https://github.com/AntixK/PyTorch-VAE) and call the CelebA dataset using the config file listed.  Specifically under the vae.yaml I have placed the path of the unzipped file where I have downloaded the celeba dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/jessicali9530/celeba-dataset) on my computer. And every time I run the program, I keep getting these errors:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/datasets/celeba.py", line 67, in **init**
' You can use download=True to download it')
RuntimeError: Dataset not found or corrupted. You can use download=True to download it
AttributeError: 'VAEXperiment' object has no attribute '_lazy_train_dataloader'

I have tried to download the dataset, but nothing changes. So I have no idea why the program is not running.
The run.py calls the experiment.py which uses this dataloader to retrieve the information:

```
def train_dataloader(self):
        transform = self.data_transforms()

        if self.params['dataset'] == 'celeba':
            dataset = CelebA(root = self.params['data_path'],
                             split = "train",
                             transform=transform,
                             download=False)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Undefined dataset type')

        self.num_train_imgs = len(dataset)
        return DataLoader(dataset,
                          batch_size= self.params['batch_size'],
                          shuffle = True,
                          drop_last=True)
```

The config file grabs the information passed on the root. So what I did was upload a few files to google colab (some .jpg files) and when I run the command stated in the GItHub, python run.py -c config/vae.yaml, it states that the dataset is not found or is corrupt. I have tried this on my linux machine and the same error occurs, even when I used the downloaded and unzip link. I have gone further to attempt to change the self.params['data_path'] to the actual path and that still does not work. Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

My pytorch version is 1.6.0.
There are two issues which I have faced. The below is my solution. It is not official but it works for me. Hope the next pytorch version will update it.

1. Issue: Dataset not found or corrupted.'

When I checked file celeba.py in pytorch library. I found this line:

```
if ext not in [".zip", ".7z"] and not check_integrity(fpath, md5):
   return False
```

This part will make self._check_integrity() return False and the program provides the message error as we got.

Solve: You can ignore this part by add "if False" immediately in front of this line

```
if False:
   if ext not in [".zip", ".7z"] and not check_integrity(fpath, md5):
      return False
```

2. celeba.py downloads dataset if you choose download=True but these two files are broken "list_landmarks_align_celeba.txt" and "list_attr_celeba.txt"

   You need to find somewhere, download and replace them

Hope these solutions will help you !!!!